# change url title if id changes - django

Tags: python, django

I have

```
def newsprofile(request, newstitle, newsid):
   newsobj = get_object_or_404(NewsModel, pk=int(newsid))
   return render(request, 'newsprofile.html', {'newsobj': newsobj})
```

but now, if I change the id `1` to `2` in url inside adressbar and hit the enter button e.g. `/sometitle_and_and_blabla/1/`,

i will get another news but the title doesnot change, it only becomes like:

```
/sometitle_and_and_blabla/2/
```

How can I change the title also if id changes?

the urls.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^news/(?P<newstitle>[^\/]*)/(?P<newsid>\d+)/$', 'newsprofile', name='newsprofile'),
```

Comment: Could you also show your `urls.py` relevant configuration? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, do you want to match both news title and id in the view? In other words, if news `1` has `title=sometitle_and_and_blabla` then url `/sometitle_and_and_blabla/2/` would return 404 - is this your desired behavior?

Comment: Need to see your template.  The backend is working, but your template is not properly displaying the title.

Comment: @alecxe nope, I want still ``id`` to be the only key to get the object. but after getting, i want the title to change to the actual news's title. does this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
def newsprofile(request, newstitle, newsid):
   newsobj = get_object_or_404(NewsModel, pk=int(newsid))
   if newstitle != newsobj.newstitle:
       return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/%s/%s/' % (newsobj.newstitle, newsid))

   .....
```

Comment: oh man, I almost got mad, didnot see the ``&``. pls update the a. it should be ``%`` :D

Answer (score 1):

As you are using named urls (e.g. `newsprofile`) I recommend the following solution. This is flexible and easy to maintain, even if your urls change as long as you use the same url parameters:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
...

def newsprofile(request, newstitle, newsid):
    newsobj = get_object_or_404(NewsModel, pk=int(newsid))

    if newsobj.newstitle != newstitle:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("newsprofile", args=[newstitle, newsid]))

    return render(request, 'newsprofile.html', {'newsobj': newsobj})
```

See [Django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) for reverse resolution of URLs.